# Difference left/right super button

Tags: 12.04, gnome, shortcut-keys

When I press my left <kbd>Super</kbd> key the gnome shell appears and when I press the right <kbd>Super</kbd> key it does not. Moreover pressing right <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> does open a terminal at once, but when using left super I have to press the <kbd>T</kbd> twice, when I press the <kbd>T</kbd> only once it is similar to just pressing the <kbd>T</kbd> without holding <kbd>Super</kbd> left. This last point also occurs with other shortcuts that I defined (like <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>), but not with <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Up/Down/Left/Right</kbd>.

What I want is to press either <kbd>Super</kbd> key to get the gnome shell and to use either <kbd>Super</kbd> key  in combination with <kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal immediately (and similar with other shortcuts). I use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and the gnome 3 shell.

Comment: In `Settings Manager -> Keyboard`, is there an option like `exo-open --launch TerminalEmulator`? If so, what does it say in the second column, shortcut?

Comment: 1) Do you mean the Keyboard section under system settings? If so I can't find it there.
2) If you mean the compiz settings-manager, I can't find it there either. 
Regardless, I tried your command in the terminal and it says that exo-open is not installed, so I highly doubt that option will be there. There is however the custom shortcut launch terminal with the command `x-terminal-emulator`. That is the one I use, since the default launch terminal does not seem to work.

Answer (score 7):

### xmodmap solution

I think you can do this using [xmodmap](http://www.xfree86.org/4.2.0/xmodmap.1.html), a tool to modify keymaps. Since my keyboard does not have a right <kbd>Super</kbd> key I cannot confirm this solution, so please leave a comment if it doesn't work.
All steps are done in a terminal

**Print the current modifier map**
Run

```
xmodmap
```

This should print the current modifier map which should like something like this

```
xmodmap:  up to 4 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock      
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3      
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

The important line is the `mod4` line, this line shows which key codes are mapped to the Super_L and Super_R key symbols.

**Backup the key map**
Before we change anything it is a good idea to backup the current key map, we can do this with

```
xmodmap -pke > ~/.xmodmap.orig
```

Now if anything goes wrong you can simply type

```
xmodmap ~/.xmodmap.orig
```

to restore your original key map. (If you made some serious mistakes and you cannot properly type anymore, a reboot also works)

**Check current key map for the** <kbd>Super</kbd> **keys**
Assuming that the <kbd>Super</kbd> keys have consecutive key codes (0x85 and 0x86 in this case) we can check the current mapping by running

```
xmodmap -pke | grep -wA1 $((0x85))
```

were of course you should change the 0x85 by the key code you have from your modifier map. This should give you

```
keycode 133 = Super_L NoSymbol Super_L
keycode 134 = Super_R NoSymbol Super_R
```

( the `$((0x85))` converts the hexadecimal number to decimal)

**Copy the behavior of the left** <kbd>Super</kbd> **to the right** <kbd>Super</kbd>
As you can see from the previous step the right <kbd>Super</kbd> key has key code 134 but we want it to have the behaviour of the left <kbd>Super</kbd> key which has keycode 133. We can do this by remapping the key using

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 134 = Super_L NoSymbol Super_L"
```

**Checking if it works**
If you now do

```
xmodmap -pke | grep -wA1 $((0x85))
```

you should see

```
keycode 133 = Super_L NoSymbol Super_L
keycode 134 = Super_L NoSymbol Super_L
```

meaning that both keys now have the same behavior. Also the modifier map should have changed on the line with `mod4`, we can check this by running

```
xmodmap | grep 'mod4'
```

which should give

```
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_L (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
```

And of course the shortcuts which you mentioned should work too!

**Make mapping persistent**
If it works, you can make sure that these settings are automatically applied when you boot. Run

```
echo 'keycode 134 = Super_L NoSymbol Super_L' >> ~/.xmodmaprc
```

to store your custom key mapping in the file `~/.xmodmaprc`. Run

```
echo 'xmodmap ~/.xmodmaprc' >> ~/.xsessionrc
```

to make sure the custom key map is executed when your window manager loads.

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer, I did everything up to Make mapping persistent. The output in the terminal was exactly as mentioned, however my problems remain the same: left super shows the gnome shell and the right one does not. And similar with shortcuts, with the left super, you'll have to press t twice to open the terminal and with the right super once is sufficient.

Comment: hmm, then I'm also clueless :P I guess these shortcuts are handled on some deeper level.

Comment: Ah, I found a bug report, apperently more people have the same issue :) https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=659899

Comment: It works to set it up but I couldn't make it persistent